# Undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Application::booted()

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

Using Lumen not Laravel, I know that this package should work with Lumen as I've installed it on an alternative microservice which is also Lumen. Can anyone help?

Trying to register the socialite providers service provider

```
$app->register(\SocialiteProviders\Manager\ServiceProvider::class);
```

When I'm greeted with,

```
(1/1) Error
Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Application::booted()
```

Issue comes from this code inside the socialite providers package.

```
$this->app->booted(function () {
    $socialiteWasCalled = app(SocialiteWasCalled::class);

    event($socialiteWasCalled);
});
```

Comment: What version of lumen are you using? Perhaps that version of the package isn't supported in the version of lumen you are using.

Comment: You sure it is supported? I believe Lumen does not have a `booted()` callback function, also according to https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/lumen/call-to-undefined-method-laravellumenapplicationbooted

Comment: Think I'm using 5.8. Their website states they support it.

Comment: Same issue. Lumen 5.6 is the version I am using.

Comment: I managed to fix it by going down a version in the `socialiteproviders/manager` package.

Comment: What version have you used instead?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a bug in that package for Lumen support. There was a commit recently to fix this issue - https://github.com/SocialiteProviders/Manager/commit/09903d33429f9f6c0da32c545c036a3e18964bbf

You should wait until this has been released, or use the `master` branch; but this isn't recommended.

Comment: Don't think this is the issue. I've tried multiple versions of the package.